# Increment user number with JMeter GUI

Tags: jmeter

I would like to execute a loop of HTTP requests with an incrementally number of users.
For example, I want something like that :

- 1st loop : 1 user
- 2nd loop : 2 users
- 3rd loop : 3 users
- ...

Is that possible with the JMeter GUI ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this effect by using the [Stepping thread group plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can gradually increase the number of concurrent users in JMeter. But not in the way you are actually asking ie, every loop / iteration!

Simply - You can not change the thread count within the test once the JMeter test has started running . But you can use variables for the user count and supply to the test before the test starts.

To gradually increase the user count, you can use any of the below thread groups

- You can use the regular thread group, ramp-up period. 100 users and 1000 seconds ramp up period, will add 1 user every 10 seconds.
- [Stepping Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/SteppingThreadGroup/)
- [Ultimate Thread Group](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/UltimateThreadGroup/)

Answer (score 0):

Actually JMeter doesn't allow this, however you can work it around using different approach, for instance if you stick to **Requests Per Minute** rather than to Virtual Users.

You can use [Constant Throughput Timer](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer) to set desired initial throughput (i.e. N requests per minute) and increment it by desired factor each Thread Group iteration.

Despite word "Constant" in its name the throughput doesn't have to be constant, it can be a [JMeter Variable or Function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) or JMeter Property.

Reference material:

- [How to use JMeter's Throughput Constant Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeters-throughput-constant-timer)
- [Beanshell Server](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server)
- [Throughput Shaping Timer](http://Throughput%20Shaping%20Timer) - an advanced version available via [JMeter Plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/), has some extra scheduling capabilities.